# Hibernate Cache not hit

Tags: hibernate, caching

im looking into the Performance of my application, and i found out that the cache is not used properly:

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.get(Grouping.class, groupId);
session.get(Grouping.class, groupId);
return (Grouping) session.get(Grouping.class, groupId);
```

every session.get creates a new database query instead of using the cache, what have i to configure?

EDIT:
OK: the problem was that the id didn't exist so he couldnt cache anything sorry

Comment: Change your comment to answer and self-accept it, please.

Comment: i dont have enough rep to answear my own question =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that the id didn't exist so he couldnt cache anything sorry